# External Link Needs To Activate A Popup

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

My website 1 needs to navigate to website 2 and my popup needs to open automatically whenever someone navigates from website 1 to website 2.

Comment: can you post your popup code?

Comment: I am using a plugin for my pop up...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in website2 header.php at top

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="http://website1.com"){
  // trigger your popup here
}
```

Comment: you can use this in your plugin.